# Is it possible to override the edit button with lwc component/aura component? how to get the id

Tags: lightning-web-components, component

In my case, I want to hide some of the fields in the standard edit page(the pop-up page after clicking the edit button in list view page)

what I try to do is to override the edit button with lwc component. But how do I get the Id of the record when I click the edit button in list view?

Answer (score 2):

For Aura, use:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride">
```

---

Note: it is not possible to actually override using LWC (for now), use an Aura wrapper, such as demonstrated in [this demo](https://gist.github.com/afawcett/d510e2d7a25daaf8b8ea9e96bbd3b4e0) by Andrew Fawcett.

---

In both cases, you'll be able to read `recordId` via the usual methods:

```
 // Aura
 myFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
   let recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
 }

 // LWC
 console.log(this.recordId);
```

Comment: thank you fox, in addition, I noticed that there is two possible cases when clicking the edit button. 1. from list view. In this case I could get the recordId with `component.get("v.recordId") according to your answer. 2. from the related list.for example, I click the edit button in related order detail list in a order record page. In this case, will I be able to get the related order detail's Id correctly (rather than get the order Id). Thank you agian for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Lanjinest Yes even in the list view `component.get("v.recordId")` will give the correct record Id. And you can pass the recordId from Aura to LWC using parameters.